# 404 ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, webforms, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to host my ASP.NET Web API (Web Forms) but I'm receiving a 404 (viewed in fiddler):

[image]

I have my Route set up in my Global and it works perfectly on my local - what am I missing here?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here's my Route template:

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Uploads",  action="UploadFile"});
```

Comment: What is your routing setup, can you share it?

Comment: What is name of your controller? What is the action name? Come on if you give info first hand, you would not have to wait for an answer.

Comment: @Aliostad sorry...just thought it was obvious. Controller is "UploadsController" and action is "UploadFile()". And this works fine locally. LMK if you need more info - thanks.

Comment: Tried this again the morning after, and the 404 was gone. Not sure what happened, but I'm not going to complain...

Comment: What did you change? Recompile? Server setting?

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but I started getting 404 responses from Web API after following a Windows Azure tutorial that told me to add a file "WebRole.cs" to my project.

After removing "WebRole.cs" from my project, my Web API calls started working again.